# How to obtain gradients with respect to parameters when using Lambda layer as output

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am trying to implement a neural network with one hidden layer that can represent the solution to a PDE (let's say the Laplace equation). The objective function therefore depends on the gradient of the neural network w.r.t its input.

Now, I have implemented the calculation of the second derivatives using Lambda layers. However when I try to compute the gradient of the output with respect to the parameters of the model, I get an error.

```py
def grad(y, x, nameit):
    return Lambda(lambda z: K.gradients(z[0], z[1]), output_shape = [1], name = nameit)([y,x])

def network(i):
    m = Dense(100, activation='sigmoid')(i)
    j = Dense(1, name="networkout")(m)
    return j

x1 = Input(shape=(1,))

a = network(x1)
b = grad(a, x1, "dudx1")
c = grad(b, x1, "dudx11")

model = Model(inputs = [x1], outputs=[c])
```

```py
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```py
x1_data = np.random.random((20, 1))
labels = np.zeros((20,1))
model.fit(x1_data,labels)
```

This is the error:

```py
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Why can't Keras compute the gradients w.r.t the trainable parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `networkout` layer. It maintains a linear activation which prevents  gradients from pass through it, and therefore, return 'None' gradients error. In this case you need to add any activation function except linear to `networkout` layer.

```
def network(i):
    m = layers.Dense(100)(i)
    j = layers.Dense(1, name="networkout", activation='relu')(m)
    return j
```

However, previous layer can have a linear activation.